# Is poolmon or an Equivalent Tool Available for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory-leak, poolmon

Is there a version of poolmon available for Windows Server 2008 64-bit? [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177415) says it only applies to versions up to Server 2003. Is this tool (or something equivalent) available for Server 2008?

(I'm new to the Windows Server world, and looking for tools to help track down an apparent kernel-space memory leak on some servers running particular web services. I would also welcome any suggestions for other tools to use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this version of poolmon works on my Windows 7 X64 bit, and on 2008 i am pretty sure

Comment: The version cited in the KB link?

Comment: The support tools download site says these tools are not supported:
Note: The Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools are not supported on 64-bit platforms.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en

Answer (score 5):

If you get the [Windows Driver Kit from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx) and install it selecting the tools option, it will install both a 32 bit and 64 bit Poolmon in the ...\Tools\Other\ folder.  Command line options can be found in [this msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550482%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513

Download Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 Update to get the tools to build, test, debug, and deploy drivers for Windows 8.1 Update, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, and ***Windows 7*.** When you have the WDK, we recommend that you install the WDK 8.1 Test Pack. It has tests for device fundamentals, graphics, imaging, mobile broadband (CDMA, GSM, and WLAN), sensors, and other utilities. Learn what's new in the WDK.